# how do i store a removed lithium ion laptop battery?

Tags: lithium-ion, battery-storage

I've taken out the dell latitude battery in order to preserve battery life since my laptop is plucked in most of the time. However, I'm not sure how to store it properly, apart from avoiding a hot place above 65 degrees which I had read from the battery. Do I need to wrap it in paper, or plastic or bubble wrap? Do I wipe it before storing and with what? Any tips would be appreciated. Attached are images of the battery.
[image: Front view]
[image: Back view]

Comment: Some laptops come with a utility that lets you set a maximum charge level for the battery. If your laptop has one the best place for the battery is in the laptop with the charge level set to around 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charge it to around 40% of the capacity, then keep it in a cool and dry place. Putting it in a plastic wrap is not a bad idea if you can make sure high humidity is not trapped in it. If it is humid environment, then when you move it to the cool environment, it might end up with water condensation and damage the battery. You can put a humidity absorber pack in the pack to limit this issue.

Make sure the battery will not freeze! A temperature of around 15 degrees Celsius should be good. The range for storage is 5 to 20 degrees.